# Saving items to display on listview

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm building an app that allows the user to save outputs, and put them to a listview. What is the best way to handle that? I thought about using a database, or saving them to a .txt file on the sdcard.

Answer (score 2):

It depends:

If you want to use those values

1. for a long period of time: store it in database.
2. for a short period: use singleton class.
3. just once, then pass it as object in the Intent-extra

saving in the .txt might need parsing the txt file also..

Comment: Well, I guess it depends on how long the user finds the item useful, so I guess a database. Thanks